# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Large message (xml with many lines) java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

WSO2 EI has a limits of rows in message?
Simple API. Send large message (xml, json) with a lot of rows (tags)

```
<inSequence>
  </respond>
<inSequence>
```

in log

> {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} - Uncaugth
> exception java.lang.StackOverflowError